# python and sql server express data storage

Tags: python, sql-server-express

I am trying to find information on how to populate database in sql server express using python and pyodbc. Most searches describe methods using sql server and NOT the express version. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: what specifically are you having trouble with? / what have you tried? Haven't done it personally but I think you can just use a regular connection string like pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServer;Database=myDB;Trusted_Connection=yes;')

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. SQL Express is just SQL Server and has exactly the same connection methods as any other SQL Server instance.

You should check that remote connections are enabled though -

1. Ensure your local Windows Firewall allows Port 1433 inbound
2. Open SQL Configuration Manager on your computer and under Network Configuration, click on protocols for SQLEXPRESS and ensure that TCP/IP is enabled.
3. Right-click on TCP/IP and selecvt Properties. On the IP Address tab under IPAll, set TCP Dynamic Ports to 0 and TCP Port to 1433 (assumes that you don't have any other SQL Server instance on your computer)

Your instance will need a restart and you can check in the error log to ensure that it is listening on TCP/IP and Port 1433